# Error received when initializing a ViteJS app

Tags: npm, vite

When I run the command below in Gitbash:

`$ npm init @vitejs/app`

I recevice the following error:

```bash
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

@vitejs/create-app is deprecated, use npm init vite instead

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9c7583f20b80c4d1\node_modules\@vitejs\create-app\index.js:43
require('create-vite')
^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9c7583f20b80c4d1\node_modules\create-vite\index.js from C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9c7583f20b80c4d1\node_modules\@vitejs\create-app\index.js not supported.
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9c7583f20b80c4d1\node_modules\create-vite\index.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js 
file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9c7583f20b80c4d1\node_modules\create-vite\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9c7583f20b80c4d1\node_modules\create-vite\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9c7583f20b80c4d1\node_modules\@vitejs\create-app\index.js:43:1) {      
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\me\Desktop
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\npx-ee21ed07.cmd
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Check out the getting started on vite. https://vitejs.dev/guide/ it's `npm create vite@latest`

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

`$npm create vite@latest`

[Further Documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project)

[GitHub Related Issue](https://github.com/vitejs/create-vite-app/issues/23)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me. I follow a website tutorial online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7AOvWpIVHU).

I got stuck at step 1.
vscode/app> npm init @vitejs/app

I used vscode/app>npm create vite@latest

Now I can continue, don't know if I will be able to complete the entire tutorial, but for now, it fixes the problem.

If you recommend another way to make an website with 3D content, let me know.